# Get shipping address for a basket in django oscar

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I am writing a view for oscar. I have the `'basket'` object. How do I access the `shipping_address` for the basket?

Answer (score 1):

There is no shipping address for the basket, there's no shipping address until it becomes an order.

You can see this from the models:

https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/1.0.1/oscar/apps/basket/abstract_models.py
grep for 'ship'... no matches

https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/1.0.1/oscar/apps/order/abstract_models.py#L68
`AbstractOrder` model has a foreign key to `order.ShippingAddress` model

Comment: But the shipping address is visible on the preview page. I want it for calculating shipping charges to a particular country.

Comment: there's no direct connection between the basket and the shipping address... it looks to me like they are two separate entities which are brought together in [`PaymentDetailsView`](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/1.0.1/oscar/apps/checkout/views.py#L371) which is responsible for creating a new `Order` instance

Comment: So, is it possible to get shipping address from PaymentDetailsView?

Comment: looks like this may be the method you need: https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/1.0.1/oscar/apps/checkout/session.py#L301 available on any of the checkout views which inherit from that `CheckoutSessionMixin`

Answer (score 1):

You should be overriding the `Repository.get_available_shipping_methods` [as recommended](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/1.5.1/src/oscar/apps/shipping/repository.py#L55).

For a dynamic implementation, you can refer to [`AbstractWeightBased` shipping method](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/1.5.1/src/oscar/apps/shipping/abstract_models.py#L99).

You may also want to checkout `django-oscar-shipping` for [their implementation / code](https://github.com/okfish/django-oscar-shipping/blob/master/oscar_shipping/checkout/session.py#L36)